# The dotnet test command ignores the creation of a file with NUnit results

Tags: teamcity, nunit-3.0, dotnet-cli

I have NUnit Test Project on .NET Core + NUnit.TestLogger (https://github.com/spekt/nunit.testlogger)
I running tests to local machine or in teamcity via cmd:

```
dotnet test --logger:nunit
```

I get the expected result:

```
Results File: D:\<PATH TO MY SOLUTION>\Source\Tests\TestResults\TestResults.xml
```

But if I run tests on Teamcity via the .NET CLI, then the TestResults.xml file is not created.
 Why?

That is, if I run the dotnet test via Command Line, the result file is created, and if through the .NET CLI (dotnet test), the file is not created

[image]

**UPD: Build Log**

```
[13:48:22][Step 3/5] dotnet.exe test MySolution.sln --logger:"nunit" @C:\teamcity-agents\BuildAgent-1\temp\agentTmp\730f901563fb4fd9b8d130e76c50cb20.rsp
[13:48:22][Step 3/5] test (5s)
[13:48:22][test] Starting: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test MySolution.sln --logger:"nunit" @C:\teamcity-agents\BuildAgent-1\temp\agentTmp\730f901563fb4fd9b8d130e76c50cb20.rsp
[13:48:22][test] in directory: C:\teamcity-agents\BuildAgent-1\work\21fca25db91ea807
[13:48:24][test] Build started, please wait...
[13:48:24][test] Build completed.
[13:48:24][test] Test run for C:\teamcity-agents\BuildAgent-1\work\21fca25db91ea807\Source\Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MySolution.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
[13:48:24][test] Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0
[13:48:24][test] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
[13:48:24][test] 
[13:48:24][test] Starting test execution, please wait...
[13:48:25][test] NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
[13:48:25][test] Running all tests in C:\teamcity-agents\BuildAgent-1\work\21fca25db91ea807\Source\Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MySolution.dll
[13:48:25][test]    NUnit3TestExecutor converted 54 of 54 NUnit test cases
...
[13:48:27][test] Total tests: 52. Passed: 52. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
[13:48:27][test] Test Run Successful.
[13:48:27][test] Test execution time: 2,8774 Seconds
[13:48:27][test] 
[13:48:27][test] Build succeeded.
[13:48:27][test]     0 Warning(s)
[13:48:27][test]     0 Error(s)
[13:48:27][test] 
[13:48:27][test] Time Elapsed 00:00:03.96
[13:48:27][test] 
[13:48:27][test] Process exited with code 0
```

Comment: Try with quotes: `--logger:"nunit"`

Comment: @Peska, I tried, does not solve the problem

Comment: no more ideas??

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solutions.
First of all @p4ulinux answer works, but in this case, you miss the integration with TeamCity, so test cases will not emerge in the Tests tab.
So, my solution is to add the next lines in the .runsettings file:

```
<LoggerRunSettings>
<Loggers>
  <Logger friendlyName="nunit" enabled="True">
    <Configuration>
      <LogFileName>test-result.xml</LogFileName>
    </Configuration>
  </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

And then point out where your .runsettins are in the step setting, in the Settings file section:

[Settings file Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1APD.png)

The results file will emerge in the TestResults folder beside your .csproj file.

That works great for me! Hope it will be useful for anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by selecting RunnerType as command line instead of dot net cli. You would need to configure it as follows :

[image]